Is my rubber plant dead? Is there any way it can come back to life? It has a strong sentimental value and I don’t wanna let her go
I repotted it a couple of months ago and the leaves drooped immediately. I was working out of town at the time and wasn’t very consistent on my watering. I thought it would come back on its own but then I moved across the country and I had it in a uhaul for a couple days. Then again I was busy getting things set up and I couldn’t look after it as much as I wanted to. Now that I’m all settled I’m giving my plants attention again but this one is clearly not happy with how things have been going. What can I do to make it feel better?

It doesn't look good but plants do have amazing powers to recover if you have the patience.  My recommendations:

cut back the stem to just above the first node where a leaf was
move to high light, preferably adjacent to a window
ensure soil has some moisture in it and reduce watering until new growth shows up

If you don't see anything after a few months then it's over.

Ok, a quick check to see if there is still hope is to take a knife or your fingernail and scratch the bark just above the soil - if it's still green and damp underneath recovery might be possible, but if it's brown or completely dry all hope is lost - hurl it in the garbage and purchase a replacement.
